# In an experiment where motivation and expectation are mediators, are they considered parellel or serial?

Tags: motivation, experiment-design, placebo

I'm trying to understand the effect of a consumer's motivation for and expectation of a product on placebo effects as mediators of a condition in a marketing context.
In the experiment, I am not sure if I should consider motivation and expectation as parallel or serial mediators.

On the one hand, from [Vroom's "Valence-Instrumentality-Expectancy" model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectancy_theory), there is a relationship between motivation and expectation, but does a relationship like this automatically imply that the mediators are serial?

I am also unsure if Vroom's theory can be applied in the first place to product marketing.